# AngularJS: consider string with leading and trailing whitespaces

Tags: angularjs

consider the following code:

```
<textarea class="normal_textarea" name="description" rows="4" cols="39" maxlength='79'  ng-model='newTimeline.description'>
</textarea>
"{{newTimeline.description}}"
```

the binding always trims the content in the textarea. But I need the whole content i.e.  with leading and trailing whitespaces. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-trim="false"`:

```
<textarea ng-trim="false" ng-model="newTimeline.description"></textarea>
```

More information at [Angularjs Document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D)